# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString not giving me desired result

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have some NSString like :

```
test = @"this is %25test%25 string";
```

I am trying to replace test with some arabic text , but it is not  replacing exactly as it is :

```
[test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"test" withString:@"اختبار"];
```

and the result is :

```
this is %25 اختبار %25 string
```

Some where I read there could be some problem with encoding or text alignment.Is there extra adjustment needed to be done for arabic string operations .

**EDIT** : I have used NSMutable string insert property but still the same result .

Comment: What encoding are you using? Is everything string literals? Running on a device or simulator?

Comment: I've seen this before -- it's somehow tied up with the RTL/DBCS nature of the language.  And based on Himanshu's comment there may be some involvement with locale.  (Ah, yes, and I recall that behavior differed between simulator and device.)

Comment: Tried what you want and this is working for me: `test: this is %اختبار% string`. I'm pretty sure you're doing it right, but can you confirm that you're assigning the `stringByReplacing...` result to a new string like this? `test = [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"test" withString:@"اختبار"];`

Comment: @Eugene: Yeah, I am assigning that . you can post what you did in answer if it is giving desired result .

Comment: @HotLicks: do you mean it will work as expected on device ?

Comment: I mean it might.  The scenario I recall was not exactly this, but similar, and there was a difference in behavior between simulator and device.  (I'm thinking the simulator failed and the device didn't.)  But remember that such effects may be due to effective locale differences, not simulator/device.

Comment: What do you get when you use Roman text instead of the Arabic(?)?  (Please copy/paste the exact text rather than retyping.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT 2:

One other thing that occurs to me that is causing most of your trouble in this specific example. You have a partially percent-encoded string above. You have spaces, but you also have %25. You should avoid doing that. Either percent-encode a string or don't. Convert it all at once when required (using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`). Don't try to "hard-code" percent-encoding. If you just used "this is a %اختبار% string" (and then percent-encoded the entire thing at the end), all your directional problems would go away (see how that renders just fine?). The rest of these answers address the more general question when you really need to deal with directionality.

---

EDIT:

The original answer after the line relates to human-readable strings, and is correct for human-readable strings, but your actual question (based on your followups) is about URLs. URLs are not human-readable strings, even if they occasionally look like them. They are a sequence of bytes that are independent of how they are rendered to humans. "اختبار" cannot be in the path or fragment parts of an URL. These characters are not part of the legal set of characters for those sections (اختبار is allowed to be part of the host, but you have to follow the IDN rules for that).

The correct URL encoding for `this is a %25<arabic>%25 string` is:

```
this%20is%20a%20%2525%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1%2525%20string
```

If you decode and render this string to the screen, it will appear like this:

```
this is a %25اختبار%25 string
```

But it is in fact exactly the string you mean (and it is the string you should pass to the browser). Follow the bytes (like the computer will):

```
this   - this    (ALPHA)
%20    - <space> (encoded)
is     - is      (ALPHA)
%20    - <space> (encoded)
a      - a       (ALPHA)
%20    - <space> (encoded)
%25    - %       (encoded)
25     - 25      (DIGIT)
%D8%A7 - ا       (encoded)
%D8%AE - خ       (encoded)
%D8%AA - ت       (encoded)
%D8%A8 - ب       (encoded)
%D8%A7 - ا       (encoded)
%D8%B1 - ر       (encoded)
%25    - %       (encoded) 
25     - 25      (DIGIT)
%20    - <space> (encoded)
string - string  (ALPHA)
```

The Unicode BIDI display algorithm is doing what it means to do; it just isn't what you expect. But those are the bytes and they're in the correct order. If you add any additional bytes (such as LRO) to this string, then you are modifying the URL and it means something different.

So the question you need to answer is, are you making an URL, or are you making a human-readable string? If you're making an URL, it should be URL-encoded, in which case you will not have this display problem (unless this is part of the host, which is a different set of rules, but I don't believe that's your problem). If this is a human-readable string, see below about how to provide hints and overrides to the BIDI algorithm.

It's possible that you really need both (a human-friendly string, and a correct URL that can be pasted). That's fine, you just need to handle the clipboard yourself. Show the string, but when the user goes to copy it, replace it with the fully encoded URL using [UIPasteboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html) or by overriding `copy:`. See [Copy, Cut, and Paste Operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH11-SW1). This is fairly common (note how in Safari, it displays just "stackoverflow.com" in the address bar but if you copy and paste it, it pastes "https://stackoverflow.com/" Same thing.

---

*Original answer related to human-readable strings.*

Believe it or not, `stringByReplacingOccuranceOfString:` is doing the right thing. It's just not displaying the way you expect. If you walk through `characterAtIndex:`, you'll find that it's:

```
% 2 5 ا ...
```

The problem is that the layout engine gets very confused around all the "neutral direction" characters. The engine doesn't understand whether you meant "%25" to be attached to the left to right part or right to left part. You have to help it out here by giving it some explicit directional characters to work with.

There are a few ways to go about this. First, you can do it the [Unicode 6.3 tr9-29](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/tr9-29.html) way with Explicit Directional Isolates. This is exactly the kind of problem that Isolates are meant to solve. You have some piece of text whose direction you want to be considered completely independently of all other text. Unicode 6.3 isn't actually supported by iOS or OS X as best I can tell, but for many (though not all) uses, it "works."

You want to surround your Arabic with FSI (FIRST STRONG ISOLATE U+2068) and PDI (POP DIRECTIONAL ISOLATE U+2069). You could also use RLI (RIGHT-TO-LEFT ISOLATE) to be explicit. FSI means "treat this text as being in the direction of the first strong character you find."

So you could ideally do this:

```
NSString *test = @"this is a %25\u2068test\u2069%25 string";
NSString *arabic = @"اختبار";
NSString *result = [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"test" withString:arabic];
```

That works if you know what you're going to substitute before hand (so you know where to put the FSI and PDI). If you don't, you can do it the other way and make it part of the substitution:

```
NSString * const FSI = @"\u2068";
NSString * const PDI = @"\u2069";

NSString *test = @"this is %25test%25 string";
NSString *arabic = @"اختبار";
NSString *replaceString = [@[FSI, arabic, PDI] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSString *result = [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"test" withString:replaceString];
```

I said this "mostly" works. It's fine for `UILabel`, and it probably is fine for anything using Core Text. But in `NSLog` output, you'll get these extra "placeholder" characters:

[image]

You might get this other places, too. I haven't checked `UIWebView` for instance.

So there are some other options. You can use directional marks. It's a little awkward, though. LRM and RLM are zero-width strongly directional characters. So you can bracket the arabic with LRM (left to right mark) so that the arabic doesn't disturb the surrounding text. This is a little ugly since it means the substitution has to be aware of what it's substituting into (which is why isolates were invented).

```
NSString * const LRM = @"\u200e";
NSString *test = @"this is a %25test%25 string";
NSString *replaceString = [@[LRM, arabic, LRM] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSString *result = [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"test" withString:replaceString];
```

BTW, Directional Marks are usually the right answer. They should always be the first thing you try. This particular problem is just a little too tricky.

One more way is to use Explicit Directional Overrides. These are the giant "do what I tell you to do" hammer of the Unicode world. You should avoid them whenever possible. There are some security concerns with them that make them forbidden in certain places (`<RLO>elgoog<PDF>.com` would display as `google.com` for instance). But they will work here.

You bracket the whole string with LRO/PDF to force it to be left-to-right. You then bracket the substitution with RLO/PDF to force it to the right-to-left. Again, this is a last resort, but it lets you take complete control over the layout:

```
NSString * const LRO = @"\u202d";
NSString * const RLO = @"\u202e";
NSString * const PDF = @"\u202c";

NSString *test = [@[LRO, @"this is a %25test%25 string", PDF] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSString *arabic = @"اختبار";
NSString *replaceString = [@[RLO, arabic, PDF] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSString *result = [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"test" withString:replaceString];
```

I would think you could solve this problem with the Explicit Directional Embedding characters, but I haven't really found a way to do it without at least one override (for instance, you could use RLE instead of RLO above, but you still need the LRO).

Those should give you the tools you need to figure all of this out. See the Unicode TR9 for the gory details. And if you want a deeper introduction to the problem and solutions, see Cal Henderson's excellent [Understanding Bidirectional (BIDI) Text in Unicode](http://www.iamcal.com/understanding-bidirectional-text/).

Comment: Nice answer ! It worked for me . But again little problem . When I copy paste that string to browser then in url I found %25%E2%80%8E in place of \u200e . Do you have any solution for this .

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "copy paste that string to browser." %25%e2%80%8e is nonsense. It's a percent sign followed by junk. Do you see this when you paste into other applications?

Comment: I mean this string that I am processing is basically a url so when I copy the output to the browser url then I am getting above weird characters .I am seeing that those characters are in the place of the \u200e .

Comment: You should convert this part of the URL into percent-encoded UTF-8 prior to trying to paste into a browser. `http://example.com/كتب` is not a well-formed URL (RFC 1738) or URI (RFC 3986). There's no promise it will be parsed correctly by anything. You should use stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:.

Comment: More importantly, though, you cannot use RLO in an URL. RLO is an actual character. It happens to be zero-width (and so invisible), but it is a character. If you include it in an URL, even if the URL were accepted, it would reference a different location than the string that lacked it. If you need computers to read this rather than humans, you will need to keep track of the actual characters you're sending, not how they happen to be displayed.

Comment: There are many ambiguous Unicode constructs that can render down to something that "looks the same" to humans. It's not practical for computers to try to figure these out in most cases, which is why it is extremely difficult to add Unicode to the URL standard. Even the limited problem of IDNs (international domain names) required significant restrictions on Unicode, and still has a number of troublesome issues.

Comment: But we are  promptly giving the string as LRO event there is arabic . How stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding will be helpful ?

Comment: Edited; this question is really about URLs, which are not the same thing as human-readable strings for display.

Comment: Slight followup: I said that %e2%80%8e is nonsense. I was misreading it. That's LRM (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this:

```
NSString *test = @"this is %25test%25 string";

NSString *test2 = [[[test stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy] componentsSeparatedByString:@"test"] componentsJoinedByString:@"اختبار"];
```

Comment: :by this I am getting %arabic% which is not desired one .